# Merge 2 GetText files

Tags: web-applications, gettext

I have two medium-sized web applications that I'm merging into one. They are both localized with `GetText` and have large amout of common strings, so merging them manually would be extremely annoying. What is the fastest way to merge the two `PO` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure `msgmerge` can be coerced into doing just that. (I mean, concat your two .po files, and let it sort things out.)

Comment: msgmerge seemed like it attempted to merge the files, but it missed cca 40% of the messages (they were missing in the result) even with the fuzzy option on.

But I did as you sat - concatenated the two files and applied msquniq on the. Worked like a charm, thanks :)

Comment: As @seanf pointed out, `msgcat` is the right tool for this, not `msgmerge`.

Answer (score 15):

`msgcat` is meant for just this thing: it concatenates and merges PO files.  `msgmerge` is for merging PO files with an updated POT file.

Answer (score 0):

"WinMerge" can be very helpful