# How to merge two .po files?

Tags: localization, internationalization, po, xgettext

I have 2 problems to merge 2 .po files.

1. I have 1 .po file(trans.po) for my applications localization, and another one (`transNew.po`) I produced recently. I need to merge them. But I when I run the following command, I will always get the same content as `transNew.pot`, there is no old translations at all.

   msgmerge --previous trans.po transNew.pot -o transfinal.po
2. I manually added some translation string using textedit to `trans.po` before, and I do not want to lose them, even above command can success, I will lose those string too. I can not find any option can solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to combine two .po translation files together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561897/is-it-possible-to-combine-two-po-translation-files-together)